# Does increasing the number of nodes in elastic increase heap size?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, circuit-breaker

I use hosted elastic and I currently have 2 zones active. At the moment I keep getting parent circuit breaker exceptions, which means my cluster doesn't have enough memory.

By adding a zone and going to 3 zones with the same cpu and ram. Will this increase my heap and decrease the number of circuit breaking exceptions. Or do I need to upgrade the zones them selves by increasing the ram and cpu?